# How can I Import Data using SQL Servers SSIS, when using foreign key constraints?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to set up an import form live database to our development database.

I trying to do this using SSIS, but the import is failing because of constraints.

E.g. I have the following tables:

- Customers
- Products
- OrderLines
- Orders

Importing Customers and Products is fine, because they do not depend on anything. But when importing OrderLines it fails because the Order is not yet created.

How do I change the order of how SSIS imports tables?

Or maybe I'm not supposed to use foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

disable or remove the foreign key constraints before the data import & then enable or add them after the import
eg.  **remove/add**

```
--drop
alter table t1  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_1
--add
alter table t1 WITH CHECK add constraint fk_1 foreign key (fk)
references t2 (i)
```

**disable/enable**

```
--disable
alter table t1 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT fk_1
--enable
alter table t1 WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT fk_1
```

The WITH CHECK is important, otherwise SQL Server will not check the data & not trust the data

Answer (score 1):

1. Import in the following order

   1. Customers
   2. Products
   3. Orders
   4. OrderLines

Foreign Keys in one table are Primary Keys in another table. Example: trying to insert OrderLines without Orders (order number), Products (Product Number) won't work.

You can also follow @Nick Kavadias idea, but that could cause voilation of business rules (although it can be caught when you try to re-enable the Constraints) having orphan records.

Comment: Well. I can not find a way to change the order.

Comment: just re-arrange your queries in the SSIS task.